# Yii2. How to set scenario in dataProvider?

Tags: yii2

I want to return different fields depends on scenario. How can I set it in dataProvider?

```
$query = User::find();
$activeData = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
     ],
]);
```

Fields in User model:

```
public function fields()
{
    if ($this->scenario == 'statistics') {
        return [
            'id',
            'email',
            'count'
        ];
    }
    return [
        'id',
        'name'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "fields" like in SQL fields (columns) or maybe somehow you want to use model scenarios, that is the validation and assigning Yii 2 mechanism?

Comment: @Bizley No, not in validation. I have updated my question, see example.

Comment: How are you returning this data? Is this for some Grid like widget?

Comment: No, it's REST API

Comment: Hmm... I was looking for a way to set scenario for the models in ActiveDataProvider collection and I can not find it anywhere. Models are populated by the provider but is there some method to instantiate them with certain properties' values? This might be the case for Yii 2 issue to be fixed or I just simply overlooked something.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the [$select](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#$select-detail) property?

```
$query = User::find()->select(['id','email','count']);
$activeData = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
     ],
]);
```

Or even better, create an [ActiveQuery](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html) class for them:

```
class UserQuery extends ActiveQuery
{
     public function statistics()
     {
        return $this->select(['id','email','count']);
     }

     /* add as many filtering functions as you need here */
}
```

Then override the `find()` method in the `User` class to use it:

```
public static function find()
{
    return new \app\models\UserQuery(get_called_class());
}
```

Then do:

```
$activeData = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => User::find()->statistics(),
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
     ],
]);
```

**Note:** In default implementation of Yii2 RESTful API you can also select the required fields within url by doing: `GET /users?fields=id,email,count`

Comment: you may also override `populate()` method in ActiveQuery to set some properties on the AR models.

Answer (score 2):

Simply get all the models using `getModels()` method, set scenario for all of them in the loop and then return data provider. Your example will change into following code:

```
$query = User::find();
$activeData = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
]);
foreach($activeData->getModels() as $model) {
    $model->scenario = 'statistics';
}
return $activeData;
```

Comment: Should be an answer

Comment: @EslamSamehAhmed Yes this may be the correct answer for most cases, but not all. In REST app for example `yii\rest\Serializer` already calls provider's `getModels()`  function internally. So doing this in a REST app will cause data to be loaded twice from database.

Comment: An alternative way is to use 2 model classes like `$query = $condition ? UserWithStats::find() : User::find();`

Comment: @SalemOuerdani Maybe this is no longer the case, because I tried it now and it didn't cause any more db queries by manually calling getModels() here as well... (I have gone away from using scenarios for the fields() method though - but that's a different matter)